# How to increase the spacing between the numbers and the product symbol in the siunitx package when the mode option is match?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, siunitx, bold

I am using the `siunitx` package for my text. To print bold numbers and units (within `\textbf{ }`) I am using the options `mode=match` and `reset-text-series=false` (see MWE). However, this way the space between the numbers and the `×` symbol gets smaller. How can I adjust the spacing to match `mode=math` without losing the ability to get bold numbers and units inside `\textbf{ }`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[%
mode=match,
reset-text-series=false,
tight-spacing = false
]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\numproduct{1 x 10 x 1e10}\par
\textbf{\unit{\ug/L}}\par
\numproduct[mode = math]{1 x 10 x 1e10}\par
\textbf{\unit[mode = math]{\ug/L}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/583

Answer (score 1):

As Joseph Wright♦ pointed out, I used `\:` to make the desired spacing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[%
mode=match,
reset-text-series=false,
tight-spacing = false,
product-symbol = \:\times\:
]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\numproduct{1 x 10 x 1e10}\par
\textbf{\unit{\ug/L}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I meant more 'this should be fixed in the current release'